# selecting HOST_NAME() triggered by application returns empty string

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, hostname, sql-server-2016

I have an `ASP.Net Core` application the connects to a `SQL SERVER 2016` DB.
The application is updating a table and causing a logging trigger to take place.

One of the things that the trigger logs is the `HOST_NAME()`.
Whenever I cause the trigger to run manually using SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio) the trigger acts as expected.
But whenever the application causes the trigger to run, the `HOST_NAME()` function logs an empty string to the logging table.

Is it something that should be set through code explicitly?
Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`HOST_NAME()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/host-name-transact-sql) just reports whatever was provided as the `Workstation ID` in the [connection string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx#Remarks). So, change your connection string (and also, be aware that its very easy for the server to be lied to, so don't rely on `HOST_NAME()` to make any security decisions)

Comment: Thanks, I just set the `WSID` parameter in the connection string to `Enviornment.MachineName` (got it from your link).